# How to resolve React Native Error: task: react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

my project was working but when i installed react-native-maps and run `react-native run-android` i got this error:
(I refer https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md and follow all steps)

```
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:12: error: package androidx.core.view does not exist
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
                         ^
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:13: error: package androidx.core.view does not exist
import androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat;
                         ^
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:73: error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
import static androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission;
                                   ^
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:73: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static androidx.core.content.PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission;
^
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
  private final GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
                ^
  symbol:   class GestureDetectorCompat
  location: class AirMapView
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:165: error: cannot find symbol
        new GestureDetectorCompat(reactContext, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            ^
  symbol:   class GestureDetectorCompat
  location: class AirMapView
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:421: error: cannot find symbol
    return checkSelfPermission(getContext(), PERMISSIONS[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
           ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(Context,String)
  location: class AirMapView
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:422: error: cannot find symbol
        checkSelfPermission(getContext(), PERMISSIONS[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        ^
  symbol:   method checkSelfPermission(Context,String)
  location: class AirMapView
E:\ReactNative-Projects\gardeshgaran\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:949: error: cannot find symbol
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
                 ^
  symbol:   variable MotionEventCompat
  location: class AirMapView
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
33 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 32 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

My Android->build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "16.1.0" 
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

My App->build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gardeshgaran"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {

       release {

           if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {

               storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)

               storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD

               keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS

               keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD

           }

       }

   }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation project(':react-native-maps')

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.gardeshgaran">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="*****"
      />


      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me solve this error!